# Initialize collections in ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a controller that should display several selects (dropdowns) with predefined values.

I display a list of **Records**, each `Record` can have a predefined `Theme` and correspond to a `City` from the list of predefined values.

In my controller I have

```
private IEnumerable<Record> records;
private static IEnumerable<Theme> themes;
private static IEnumerable<City> cities;

private async Task<bool> LoadThemes()
{
    themes = await repository.GetTableEntitiesAsync<Theme>(lang);
    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> LoadCities()
{
    themes = await repository.GetTableEntitiesAsync<City>(lang);
    return true;
}
```

and the action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // records = from DB, then
    await LoadThemes(); ViewData["themes"] = this.themes;
    await LoadCities(); ViewData["cities"] = this.cities;

    return View(records);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    // record => from id, then
    await LoadThemes(); ViewData["themes"] = this.themes;
    await LoadCities(); ViewData["cities"] = this.cities;

    return View(record);
}
```

Since I can't do a *async* constructor, nor I am sure passing via `Index` view, how can I initialize my "static" collections only once?

Comment: are you loading cities or themes in the LoadCities() method ? i.e. `cities = await...`

Comment: I edited the OP to explain that point

Comment: Static variables in a controller are a poor substitute for implementing real caching. And returning a boolean from a method with the only value being returned being `true` doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use static variable in that scenario. Instead, you just store them in local variables.

**View**

```
<form asp-controller="Index" asp-action="Sample" method="post">
    <select asp-for="Cities" asp-items="@Model.Cities"></select>
    <select asp-for="ThemeId" asp-items="@Model.Themes"></select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class RecordViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ThemeId { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Themes { get; set; }            
    public IList<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }

    public RecordViewModel()
    {
        Themes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var lang = "???";
    var model = new RecordViewModel
    {
        Themes = (await repository.GetTableEntitiesAsync<Theme>(lang))
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem {Value = x.Id,Text = x.Text}),
        Cities = (await repository.GetTableEntitiesAsync<City>(lang))
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Text })
    };
    return View(model);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    var lang = "???";
    var model = new RecordViewModel
    {
        Id = id,
        Themes = (await repository.GetTableEntitiesAsync<Theme>(lang))
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Text }),
        Cities = (await repository.GetTableEntitiesAsync<City>(lang))
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Text })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

**Other Thoughts**

*If you do not want to create two views - one for create and one for edit, you might want to consider creating a partial view `_CreateOrUpdate.cshtml`,and share it between them like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/tree/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Areas/Administration/Views/Users). Here are corresponding [Create](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L85) and [Edit](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L138) methods.*

*If you do not want to query database everytime, you might want to consider using MemoryCache like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Settings/SettingRepository.cs#L11).*

Comment: ok, but the list of themes and cities don't change. is the same list of const values. Is it really necessary to load it each time in each view? I mean, could I load it once again in the controller's constructor and use it for all the views?

Comment: It is not a good practice to use static variable to cache data in that scenario. Besides, we rarely use static/singleton in web application. Instead, you should consider using MemoryCache.

Comment: We should not load data inside constructor not to mention ***constructor cannot be async***. Otherwise, we will be query data everytime web hid that controller, although some action methods doesn't require them.

Comment: Perhaps I should take a look on the MemoryCache solution then... :)

Comment: Yes, [here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Settings/SettingRepository.cs#L11) is the sample code using MemoryCache.